# How can i get Vertex ai managed notebook in my local vs code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-code

I am able to connect to the project using google cloud code, but it lists only user managed notebooks and VMs. How can i SSH into Managed notebooks.

I have tried this, but its for user managed notebooks and not for managed notebooks.
https://medium.com/google-cloud/choose-the-ide-you-want-and-develop-on-vertex-ai-workbench-part-i-94d19ca1d2ff

Answer (score 0):

We currently do not support this, but I made a [Feature Request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode/issues/817) to track this in Cloud Code's github repository.